# MySQL Average unique x for day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

I'm trying to get a MySQL query together to get the average amount of unique devices from a table which logs mac addresses, for each day of the week in a given month and year. So far i have this to count all devices.

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date_time) dow, 
DAYOFWEEK(date_time) day_num, 
COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) as devices
FROM detected_devices 
WHERE client_id = 11
AND venue_id = 1
AND EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date_time) = 2010
AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_time) = 12
GROUP BY dow
ORDER BY day_num
```

Thats getting me the total number of devices but i can't seem to use the AVG function too. I've tried this line instead but get error #1111 - Invalid use of group function when i do.

```
AVG( COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) ) as devices
```

Comment: Have you tried `AVG( DISTINCT (mac)) as devices`?

Comment: Ah, that does return some results yes, thanks. However, the results seems a little odd.. for example - Monday = 19291096024292.0804 devices! Where the count function above returned 52

Comment: I presume thats actually getting the average of each distinct mac address which would give that kind of value. I need the AVG of a COUNT  of DISTINCT macs really

Comment: `Returns the average value of expr. The DISTINCT option can be used as of MySQL 5.0.3 to return the average of the distinct values of expr.`, which version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you can't `GROUP BY` an alias. Try `GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(date_time)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the GROUP BY seems to be working fine. It's more the AVG part which is not.